# How to satisfy both time complexity and space complexity in the sorting problem?

Tags: c, sorting, time-complexity, out-of-memory, space-complexity

I am trying to sort the numbers in ascending order by using the bubble sort algorithm. However, I still get an OufOfMemory error.

How can I make sure that I cannot get an OufOfMemory error in my code?

The problem is like the following sentences.

- There is a **limitation of the memory capacity of 8MB.**
- There is a **limitation of a time of 5 seconds.**
- The number of numbers N (1 ≤ N ≤ 10,000,000) is given in the first line.
- Numbers are given in N lines from the second line. This number is a natural number less than or equal to 10,000.

  https://www.acmicpc.net/problem/10989

Here are the codes that I have tried to print numbers.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void swap(int* x, int* y){
    int tmp = *x;
    *x = *y;
    *y = tmp;
}

int main(){

    int N, i, j;
    scanf("%d", &N);

    int* arr;
    arr = (int*)malloc(N * sizeof(int));

    for(i=0;i<N;i++){
        scanf("%d", &arr[i]);
    }
    
    int min_value = arr[0];
    for(i=0;i<N;i++){
        for(j=0;j<N-i-1;j++){
            if(arr[j] > arr[j+1]) {
                swap(&arr[j], &arr[j+1]);
            }
        }
    }

    for(i=0;i<N;i++){
        printf("%d\n", arr[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void swap(int* x, int* y){
    int tmp = *x;
    *x = *y;
    *y = tmp;
}

int main(){

    int N;
    int i, j;
    scanf("%d", &N);

    long* arr;
    arr = (long*)malloc(N * sizeof(int));

    for(i=0;i<N;i++){
        scanf("%ld", &arr[i]);
    }

    for(i=0;i<N;i++){
        for(j=0;j<N-i-1;j++){
            if(arr[j] > arr[j+1]) {
                swap(&arr[j], &arr[j+1]);
            }
        }
    }

    for(i=0;i<N;i++){
        printf("%ld\n", arr[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

When I guess the reason for the out-of-memory, it seems that the memory exceed is caused by N * sizeof(int) in dynamic allocation. If N ranges up to 10,000,000, the worst case is N * int is 2.097.152. The result exceeds memory.

Also, I calculated 8 MB of memory like the following sentence.

8 * 1024 * 1024 / 4 = 2.097.152

Here's the desired result:

- Satisfy the time constraints of 5 seconds.
- Satisfy the memory constraints of 8MB.

[This](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/memory-limit-exceeded-error/) is related to my question, but it doesn't solve my problem.

Thank you for reading my post.

Comment: Presumably you are not required to use bubble sort. Any time you are given additional bounding information in a programming question ("this number is a natural number less than or equal to 10,000") you should expect to use that information in some way to help solve the problem. It will almost always be a clue.

Answer (score 1):

An `int` could be larger than necessary to store a number in 0..10,000. This is in fact likely. You could use a `int16_t` or `uint16_t`. But an array of these would still take up 20 MB or over 19 MiB. This means you can't possibly place all the numbers in memory at once.

This rules out Bubble Sort. In fact, this rules out all conventional sorts (since you presumably can't use external storage either).

But since we're sorting small numbers, we can use unconventional sorting approaches, such as a [Counting Sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort). We would need an array of 10,001 `uint32_t` objects, which is to say just over 40 KB or under 40 KiB. This is well below your limit.

---

On the time side, Bubble Sort is extremely inefficient and might not have been fast enough for your objective.

You won't have any time issues with a Counting Sort.